# Failed to retrieve data from database Vendor Code 2812 (Crystal Reports)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I have Installed the Crystal Reports for Visual Studio.Net 2010 (CRforVS_13_0_4) and created many reports, those reports are working fine with the following code as long as my PC is same where i have created the report. (Reports are created with Stored Procedures in backend)....But when i moved to another PC all reports are giving error.

```
Failed to retrieve data from database" 
Details: [Database Vendor Code 2812] 
Error in File ItemTypesReport (ItemTypes Report is the Crystal Report)
```

Following is my code.

```
Public Sub Preview_ReportWithParameters(ByVal CrystalReportName As String)
        Try
            If SqlConn.State = 1 Then SqlConn.Close()
            Dim frmReport As New ReportDisplay
            Dim crDocument As New ReportDocument


            Dim reportPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\" + CrystalReportName + ".rpt"
            crDocument.Load(reportPath)
            crDocument.SetParameterValue("@UserID", Convert.ToInt64(mUserID))
            crDocument.SetParameterValue("@ActionCode", "1")
            crDocument.SetParameterValue("@SearchText", "")


            Dim crConnectionInfo As ConnectionInfo = New ConnectionInfo()
            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = mSQLServername
            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = mSQLDatabaseName
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = mSQLUser
            crConnectionInfo.Password = mSQLPassword
            Dim crTables As Tables = crDocument.Database.Tables
            For Each crTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In crTables
                Dim crTableLogonInfo As TableLogOnInfo = crTable.LogOnInfo
                crTableLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
                crTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crTableLogonInfo)
            Next
            frmReport.crViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
            frmReport.crViewer.DataBindings.Clear()
            frmReport.crViewer.ReportSource = crDocument
            frmReport.Show()
            frmReport.Refresh()
            SqlConn.Close()
            'crDocument.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'If Err.Number = 5 Or Err.Number = 91 Then
            '    MsgBox("Sorry, no record is selected to preview, you must select a record.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No record selected")
            'Else
            MsgBox("Error No: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "No record selected")
            'End If
        End Try
    End Sub
```

To Call the above Procedure

```
Preview_ReportWithParameters("ItemTypesReport")
```

Comment: Check to make sure that the user on the other PC has permissions to access the SQL database.

Comment: That is not a problem, i have same copy of database on two PC's (My local PC and Server)...Application itself is accessing data from both PC's if change the connectionString at runtime....but Crystal Report is not get Connection String for Server, its getting only Local PC as they were developed in Local PC.............Also this is the same code i was using in VS 2008 with Crystal Reports and it was working fine with multiple connection String and now i moved to VS 2010 and Crystal Reports for VS 2010 and its start giving above error.